# How to differentiate between time to live and time to idle in ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache

The docs on ehache says:

```
timeToIdleSeconds: Sets the time to idle for an element before it expires.
i.e. The maximum amount of time between accesses before an element expires

timeToLiveSeconds: Sets the time to live for an element before it expires.
i.e. The maximum time between creation time and when an element expires.
```

I understand **timeToIdleSeconds**

But does it means that after the creation & first access of a cache item, the **timeToLiveSeconds** is not applicable anymore ?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

`timeToIdleSeconds` enables cached object to be kept in as long as it is requested in periods shorter than `timeToIdleSeconds`. `timeToLiveSeconds` will make the cached object be invalidated after that many seconds regardless of how many times or when it was requested.

Let's say that `timeToIdleSeconds = 3`. Then the object will be invalidated if it hasn't been requested for 4 seconds.

If `timeToLiveSeconds = 90`, then the object will be removed from cache after 90 seconds, even if it has been requested few milliseconds in the 90th second of its short life.

Comment: So I presume we always want to set idletime < ttl

Comment: In the comment above when you say that "Let's say that timeToIdleSeconds = 3. Object will be invalidated if it hasn't been requested for 4 seconds.", when you say invalidate - what does it mean? Does it remove it from heap?
If the object is removed from cache, then I am confused about what is the use of timeToLive parameter at all.
When we did the POC, we are seeing that data is fetched from source after timetoIdleseconds. Although the timetoLive is a much higher value, I would have expected that it is fetched from cache since the timetoLive is much higher value than timeToIdle in our case.

Comment: @Gayathri If you had a data item that is accessed often (every two seconds) but has a TTL of sixty seconds.  It would still be pulled from source once every sixty seconds even if it is accessed continually (never idle).

Comment: As follow-up to first comment (by @JacquesRenéMesrine).
For the case both TTL & TTI set (i.e. greater than zero):
1) TTI  >= TTL: TTI has *no effect*. Entry is considered _expired_ after `creationTime + TTL`
2) TTI  < TTL: Entry is considered _expired_ after `min((max(lastAccessTime, creationTime) + TTI), (creationTime + TTL))`

Comment: "irregardless" -> "regardless"

Answer (score 47):

If you set both, the `expirationTime` will be `Math.min(ttlExpiry, ttiExpiry)`, where

```
ttlExpiry = creationTime + timeToLive
ttiExpiry = mostRecentTime + timeToIdle
```

Full source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.0/net/sf/ehcache/Element.java#Element.getExpirationTime%28%29).

Comment: Now the behaviour makes sense for me. Thanks for pointing this out, especially the `Math.min` part.

Comment: This code makes it more clear than human explanation above :-)

Answer (score 22):

From the [old 1.1 documentation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aHAY-qhRmmYsJ%3aehcache.org/documentation/documentation-1_1.html%20ehcache%20timeToLiveSeconds%20infinite&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&source=www.google.com.au) (available in Google Cache, which is easier to browse and more informative than the current docs AFAIK):

> **timeToIdleSeconds**
>
> This is an optional attribute.
>
> Legal values are integers between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE.
>
> It is the number of seconds that an Element should live since it was
>   last used. Used means inserted or accessed.
>
> 0 has a special meaning, which is not to check the Element for time to
>   idle, i.e. it will idle forever.
>
> The default value is 0.
>
> **timeToLiveSeconds**
>
> This is an optional attribute.
>
> Legal values are integers between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE.
>
> It is the number of seconds that an Element should live since it was
>   created. Created means inserted into a cache using the Cache.put
>   method.
>
> 0 has a special meaning, which is not to check the Element for time to
>   live, i.e. it will live forever.
>
> The default value is 0.